# Is it good practice to use global variables in recursion

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, recursion

I'm helping someone on his school assignment - we're trying to write recursive function (if it matters - either in PHP or JavaScript).

I understand principles of recursion quite well, but I haven't wrote any of those from "academic" viewpoint.

Is it good practice to use global variable to store result, something like:

```
var results = [];

var rec = function(a) {
    ...
    if (match)
        results.push(someValue);
}
```

Or should I use return for collecting all those results back together (which would be much more difficult)?

Comment: It would probably be better to not use a global variable and just return an array each time adding an element to the array.

Comment: Thought about this - but that array will get branches (for my given task) and dealing with returns would take biggest part of code. Therefore I got that naughty idea to use global.

Comment: It is not better to use a global variable.  Since arrays are passed by pointer, it's simple to pass the array you are operating on into the function and then just operate on the array passed in.  This avoids the global and the inherent disadvantages of globals in Javascript.

Comment: If you are using JS and don't want a global variable, you could always wrap it in a closure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is good practice to use as little global variables as possible, preferrably none<sup>**1**</sup>.

To avoid the need for a global variable in recursion, you can use an inner function that uses a closure:

```
var rec = function(a) {
    var someValue = [];
    function dorec() {
      // stuff happens
      if (match)
        results.push(someValue);
      }
    }
    dorec();  
}
```

<sup>**1**</sup> [**Douglas Crockford**](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) states

> All variables should be declared before used. JavaScript does not
>   require this, but doing so makes the program easier to read and makes
>   it easier to detect undeclared variables that may become implied
>   globals. Implied global variables should never be used. Use of global
>   variables should be minimized.

Comment: Thank you all from your comments. I wasn't concerned by usage of globals per se - I was just unsure, is such programming pattern allowed. But from those examples I understand, it's not and issue. So as tweak to my code, I'm going to use closure instead of global.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the existing comments and to give you a concrete example, here is the code for recursively adding the even numbers to the given array:

```
var match;
var rec = function(a, res) {
    if (a < 0) {
        return res;
    }

    match = a % 2 == 0;

    if (match) {
        res.push(a);
    }
    return rec(a - 1, res);
}

var results = rec(10, []);

alert(results);
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xukukggL/